# Are the URLs encouraged by AngularJS routing consistent with REST principles?

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm writing an AngularJS app using the routing feature, but this is producing URLs that look like this:

```
http://localhost/admin.html#/surveys/2/schedule
```

Is this kind of URL, with the `.html#` in the middle of it, OK from a RESTful perspective? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

It's technically not RESTful, because everything after the hash (`#`) will never make it to the server.

I don't think `$routeProvider` is necessarily *encouraging* those URLs as much as it's worrying about older browsers that don't support HTML5/popState.  If you want to get away from using hash in your URLs, you can include the `$locationProvider` and call `.html5Mode(true)`: [http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Just to clarify, even if you switch to use the `$locationProvider`, your URLs will be the only thing RESTful about your site.  REST is more than just pretty/usable URLs... if you're using AngularJS, you'll still (read: you still should be) just be serving up HTML and not actually modifying anything on the server from your site.  If you're thinking about REST, you should be more worried about setting up a RESTful web service and getting AngularJS talking to it.